# How to get my 'Add Item' button to work on my JSP so that it can submit data into my Database

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, hibernate, jsp

I hope you guys are doing well. I was wondering, if someone can help me figure out how I can make the 'Add' button in my JSP page below work properly so that it can add data to the database. I'm trying to make sure that the added data shows up both on the table and gets inserted into my MySql database. I've got the delete button to function properly, but am not sure how to even approach the situation with the 'Add' button. I want it to prompt the user to enter a title and author for the book, then add it.

[image]

I'm using a JavaScript file to create functionality of the buttons and did it just fine with the Delete button. This is how I made it for the delete button:

```
$('span.deleteall').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var mediaPageName = window.location.pathname;
    var mediaType = null;
    if(mediaPageName.includes('books')){
        mediaType = 'Book';
    }else if(mediaPageName.includes('movies')){
        mediaType = 'Movie';
    }else if(mediaPageName.includes('music')){
        mediaType = 'Music';
    }else if(mediaPageName.includes('contacts')){
        mediaType = 'Contact';
    }
    var $this = $(this), 
        $trows = $this.closest('table').children('tbody').find('tr.selected'),
        sel = !!$trows.length;
    // Don't confirm delete if no rows selected.
    if(!sel){
        alert('No rows selected');
        return false;
    }
    var c = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the slected rows?');
    if(!c) { return false; }
    $trows.fadeOut(function(){ $trows.remove(); zebra(); deleteFromDatabase(mediaType,$trows.find('td:last').text());});
});
```

I think I have to do something similar for the 'Add' button in the JS file, but where I'm getting confused is how to create a new prompt that asks the user to enter a title and author before submitting.

I'm also using a HibernateDAO.java class that has methods to add books and delete books, along with a controller class that has the proper mappings.

Example:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deleteBook/{booksKey}", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public void deleteBook(@PathVariable String booksKey, HttpServletRequest request){
        System.out.println("BOOK KEY TO DELETE:" + booksKey);
        HibernateDataDAO dao = new HibernateDataDAO();
        int intBooksKey = Integer.parseInt(booksKey);
        dao.deleteBooks(intBooksKey);
    }
@RequestMapping(value="/addBook/{booksKey}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addBook(@PathVariable String booksKey, HttpServletRequest request){
        System.out.println("BOOK KEY TO ADD:" + booksKey);
        HibernateDataDAO dao = new HibernateDataDAO();
        int intBooksKey = Integer.parseInt(booksKey);
        dao.addBooks(intBooksKey);
```

DAO class:

```
public void deleteBooks(int booksKey){
    createDatabaseConnection();
    Statement stmt = null;
    String sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM books " +
                 "WHERE booksKey =" + booksKey;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);
        System.out.println("Deleted book key: " + booksKey);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

public void addBooks(int booksKey){
        createDatabaseConnection();
        Statement stmt = null;
        **String sqlQuery = "";**
    try{
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);
        System.out.println("Added book key: " + booksKey);
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm not sure how to correctly write the SQL query for the addBooks method above.

Also, here's a snapchat of how my DB looks like in MySQL:

[image]

Lastly, here is the code for my buttons on my JSP page:

```
 <th colspan="2"><span href="javascript:;" id= "formsubmit" class="btn btn-default deleteall" title="dtable">Delete Selected Items</span></th>
 <th colspan="2"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Add Item</a></th>
```

If someone can please show me how to get the Add button to work properly, or atleast show me how to code it so that it prompts the user to enter the Title and Author, that would definitely help and give a good understanding on how to complete this. I believe this has more to do with the JS file and JSP. I'm really weak at JS and that's why this is an issue for me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are going to have many screens and tables and want to properly update theme and work with your backend through REST web services, it's better to use a **client side UI framework** (Angularjs, ReactJS, etc.) otherwise you will be trapped in many spaghetti JS code to handle your UI logic.

For Now: you can use a lightweight modal plugin [remodal](http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/) to show your form in a modal window. So in the click event of your add button, you must show your modal window.

In the modal, you must have name field and a button, and in the button, get value of field (`var name = $(#myField).val()`).

Then you need to make an Ajax call to your rest service and pass the name variable to Ajax request. in the **Success** callback of your request, you must add the result to your table:

```
success(function(data){/*returned data from REST service*/

    $('#myTable').append(/* HTML OF YOUR NEW ROW */);
})
```

in the failure callback of your button, you can alert user with appropriate message.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, thanks :) This is my first time doing a project like and have got a ton to learn. I think I'll update the controllers to reflect the 'Add' button, thereby making it easier for you to help me!

Comment: I went ahead and updated the post with my controller for addBooks, my DAO for addBooks, and posted a screenshot of how my DB looks like right now. I think this'll help you better understand my question.

Comment: Updated my answer, feel free to question about it.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure where to begin, can you guide me exactly where I need to be inputting this in my code? I'm an absolute beginner in JS and honestly, I'm even surprised I was able to get the delete button to work after numerious amounts of guessing and piecing code.

Comment: I suggest you begin with adding a simple modal with a message , and bind your add button click to a function that will show the modal. read Remodal plugin page documentation.